# Filter a mysql query with conditions / Group the result

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table (see below) which contains a lot email addresses. I want to select X(20) entries from this table but only Y(2) from each domain. Is this possible with sql? If I use `Group by` only one domain will be used. But it should be variable how many domains are used per Query.

**The Table**

```
id | email        | domain
---|--------------|--------
1  | foo@bar.de   | bar.de
2  | baz@bar.de   | bar.de
3  | admin@bar.de | bar.de
4  | info@bar.de  | bar.de
5  | bar@foo.com  | foo.com
6  | baz@foo.com  | foo.com
```

**The Result should be**

ID: 1,2,5,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want two entries for each domain, then you can do:

```
select t.*
from thetable t
where (select count(*)
       from thetable t2
       where t2.domain = t.domain and t2.id <= t.id
      ) <= 2;
```

If you have a larger table, there are more efficient methods.

I have no idea what `X(20)` is supposed to mean.

Comment: Thank You! This seems to work. The X(20) means the maximal amount of results. Can you give me a hint for the more efficient methods? So I can have a loot at them as well.

Comment: @Skat0r . . . You need to use variables.  How much data do you have?  For a small data set, this is fine, particularly with an index on `(domain, id)`.

Comment: The table is used as a queue with maybe 1000-2000 rows. So I think I should be fine?